# WPF mvvm Button (ICommand) CanExecute not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have this xaml and this Code. 
My Problem is Confirm does not Change.
The CanExecute  is nonly execut one times.

```
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Connection String"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding  Path=ConnectionString,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ></TextBox>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Content="Load"  Command="{Binding BtnLoad,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Content="Confirm" Command="{Binding BtnConfirm}"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  Content="Add" Command="{Binding BtnAdd,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```
    public MainViewModel(ILogRepository logRepository)
    {

        _logRepository = logRepository;

        _listOfLogs = new List<Log>();
        BtnAdd = new BtnAdd(AddLog);
        BtnConfirm = new BtnConfirm(ConfimLog, LogIsSelected);
        BtnLoad = new BtnLoad(LoadLogTable);

    }
    private bool LogIsSelected()
    {
        // return true;
        //Funktionerit im WPF nicht
        if (_selectedLogItem != null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You seem to be having some trouble with some code you didn't show us. Please show us that code by editing your question and adding the code to your question. You probably need to raise the command's `CanExecuteChanged` event when its ability to execute changes. If you don't do that, the button won't know it needs to call CanExecute again.

Comment: You can remove `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` from those bindings. The Command property will never create a new Command object and assign it back to your viewmodel property, so there's no need to tell it exactly when to do that. Even if it were willing to try, your property is probably readonly anyway.

Comment: To clarify: The code you didn't show us was the command itself. What determines whether or not it can execute?

Comment: Logisselected is private. I would think it needs to be public for the view to get any value. You also need some user ui interaction or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested?view=netframework-4.8 before it wouod be checked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example showing you how the can-execute method works. The confirm button becomes enabled when there is text in the connection string input field. It's not exactly like your code, but you are referring to a list  I don't see in your XAML.

MainWindow.xaml (nothing in the code behind)

```
<Window x:Class="FrameworkCanExecuteExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FrameworkCanExecuteExample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="300"
        Height="100">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Connection string:" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=ConnectionString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Content="Confirm"  Command="{Binding BtnConfirm}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace FrameworkCanExecuteExample
{
    public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string connectionString;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            BtnConfirm = new RelayCommand(Confirm, CanConfirm);
        }

        public string ConnectionString
        {
            get => connectionString;
            set
            {
                connectionString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand BtnConfirm { get; }


        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void Confirm(object parameter)
        {
        }

        private bool CanConfirm(object parameter)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

RelayCommand.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace FrameworkCanExecuteExample
{
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> execute;
        private Func<object, bool> canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return canExecute == null || canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```